# UUID got lost in translation?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a MySQL table with UUID as id. When I select (in MySQL Workbench), I get:

```
269ecb9e-b7fe-11e6-a630-657416131b50
667d6caa-b800-11e6-a630-657416131b50
6f94b93c-b734-11e6-8618-ba2ba7c3db03
ab8478b8-b7fe-11e6-a630-657416131b50
ddb6b7d8-b80d-11e6-a630-657416131b50
fc031a90-b805-11e6-a630-657416131b50
```

Then I query in Java using Hibernate, and I get:

```
32363965-6362-3965-2d62-3766652d3131
36363764-3663-6161-2d62-3830302d3131
36663934-6239-3363-2d62-3733342d3131
61623834-3738-6238-2d62-3766652d3131
64646236-6237-6438-2d62-3830642d3131
66633033-3161-3930-2d62-3830352d3131
```

As you can see, I really don't get the same result.

My database schema uses a char(36) and is as:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique identifier as a UUID.',
  `fragment` text COMMENT 'Generic field. '
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My Hibernate POJO is:

```
package net.jgp.map.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "table", catalog = "z_map")
public class ExternalMapping {

    private String id;
    private String fragment;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public UUID getId() {
        return java.util.UUID.fromString(this.id);
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id.toString();
    }

    @Column(name = "fragment")
    public String getFragment() {
        return this.fragment;
    }

    public void setFragment(String fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }
}
```

The rest is classic Hibernate code (happy to share if helpful).

My first attempt was without the toString() stuff and using UUID natively in the POJO code, but the result was the same.

Comment: As a side note, if using Postgres is an option, it has a native UUID column type that Hibernate will map. (In this case, I usually recommend using a time-based UUID generator instead of random to improve physical row locality for related records.)

Comment: As the database column is char(36), why do you have an id field and then when calling getId(), you return a UUID? Also, I think your annotations should be on the fields, not on the getters.

Comment: @chrylis unfortunately, the choice of DB is not an option. I like PostgreSQL better for plenty of reasons. I really like your idea of time based, however, I have datetimes in another column on which I can partition if needed.

Comment: @TurbutAlin The storage of the UUID is char(36), but what I really want to manipulate in the UUID, not a String.